# How can I show a specific list of apps in the share sheet in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a Kotlin beginner and I'm aware that this question is asked probably a hundred times already, so sorry in advance to anyone who feels annoyed...

I'm working on an app which is supposed to send a picture the user took in the app to specific other apps (instagram, facebook, wechat) via share sheet. The User should not be able to choose from all the apps that are installed. The share sheet should only show instagram, facebook and wechat. This is where my problem begins...

How can I use the share sheet to send the user only to instagram, facebook and wechat? 
Via PackageManager? Do I have to filter all the other Packages? 
I hope my question is clear enough. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: welcome to SO. instead of saying that a question has been asked and answered many times before, you should instead try to focus on what you've tried and what doesn't work as you expect it to. what are the current solutions not doing that you're looking for ? please include your code and add some details to your question

Comment: "The share sheet should only show instagram, facebook and wechat" -- what if the user does not have any of those? What if the user does not want to use any of those? "The User should not be able to choose from all the apps that are installed" -- what if the user wants to use a different app?